# Is there a way to pass in environment variables to python script?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-unittest, django-tests

I am trying to write a python test that involves testing if the environment variables provided are valid. I am passing the environment variables as follows 
`env = EnvironmentVarGuard()` `env.set('GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS', GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS)`
The `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` is an import from a python file.
the `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` works while in a `.env` but once I do the import from a file I receive the following error

```
self.__credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(
  File "/Users/esir/CFA/DebunkBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/service_account.py", line 251, in from_json_keyfile_dict
    return cls._from_parsed_json_keyfile(keyfile_dict, scopes,
  File "/Users/esir/CFA/DebunkBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/service_account.py", line 185, in _from_parsed_json_keyfile
    signer = crypt.Signer.from_string(private_key_pkcs8_pem)
  File "/Users/esir/CFA/DebunkBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/_pure_python_crypt.py", line 167, in from_string
    marker_id, key_bytes = pem.readPemBlocksFromFile(
  File "/Users/esir/CFA/DebunkBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyasn1_modules/pem.py", line 44, in readPemBlocksFromFile
    substrate = ''.encode().join([base64.b64decode(x.encode()) for x in certLines])
  File "/Users/esir/CFA/DebunkBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyasn1_modules/pem.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    substrate = ''.encode().join([base64.b64decode(x.encode()) for x in certLines])
  File "/Users/esir/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

the part using the env variable is
`ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(json.loads(os.getenv('GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS'), strict=False), scopes=self.__scope)`

so my question is why does it work if I just set the `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` on the `.env` file but fails if I try using `EnvironmentVarGuard`

***Update*** Here is how I am using the EnvironmentVarGuard

```
env = EnvironmentVarGuard()
env.clear()
env.set('GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS', GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS)
```

Comment: How are you using you `EnvironmentVarGuard`? Can you share the test case where it is contained, including the `env.set` use?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte I have updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/test.html#test.support.EnvironmentVarGuard) I believe you should be using it as a [ContextManager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) as shown below:

```
from test.support import EnvironmentVarGuard
with EnvironmentVarGuard() as env:
    env.clear()
    env.set('GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS', GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS)
    # put your code inside context manager
```